# How to avoid scripts installed by Pip in editable mode generating "ResourceWarning: unclosed file" messages?

Tags: python-3.x, pip, setuptools

When using "pip" to install packages in editable mode (using the "-e") flag, any executable scripts will produce annoying "ResourceWarning: unclosed file " messages when invoked.

To reproduce, consider the following minimal package:

```
foo/
    bin/foo.py
    setup.py
```

where "setup.py" has:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='foo',
    version='0.1',
    scripts=["bin/foo.py"],
    zip_safe=False)
```

and "bin/foo.py" has, e.g.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

print("hello, world")
```

Then, upon running:

```
python3 -m pip install -e foo
```

invoking the executable results in:

```
$ foo.py 
/.../bin/foo.py:6: ResourceWarning: unclosed file <_io.TextIOWrapper name='/.../foo/bin/foo.py' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>
hello, world
```

The issue is the dummy script stub that is auto-generated and installed in the user binary directory by "pip" in editable mode invokes the source script using the following statement:

```
exec(compile(open(__file__).read(), __file__, 'exec'))
```

The file is indeed opened without closing. It is simple to fix it manually. But how can we get "pip" to do it correctly by itself?

(Note that this problem does not occur when "editable" mode is not used, as here the executable script is copied directly instead of being called by a wrapper script).

Comment: While @wim's answer solves your issue perfectly, maybe you can consider replacing the script with [automatic script creation via `entry_points` keyword](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#automatic-script-creation). This will autogenerate the executable scripts calling code from your module, so nothing will be `exec`ed in the first place.

Comment: Thanks @hoefling. Good to know about this alternate approach. I accepted the answer below, but I think that if this was a full answer it would be acceptable as well because it does provide a clean, general approach that does not require any hackery. It does require a little bit of reorganization of library code/scripts though. Of course, with the PR being accepted by pip, it seems that we will have a clean upstream solution soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## try:

You will find the template in the site-packages dir, with the filename `script (dev).tmpl`:

```
$ cat ".venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/script (dev).tmpl"
# EASY-INSTALL-DEV-SCRIPT: %(spec)r,%(script_name)r
__requires__ = %(spec)r
__import__('pkg_resources').require(%(spec)r)
__file__ = %(dev_path)r
exec(compile(open(__file__).read(), __file__, 'exec'))
```

Edit it how you want, for example:

```
# EASY-INSTALL-DEV-SCRIPT: %(spec)r,%(script_name)r
__requires__ = %(spec)r
__import__('pkg_resources').require(%(spec)r)
__file__ = %(dev_path)r
try:
    f = open(__file__)
    exec(compile(f.read(), __file__, 'exec'))
finally:
    f.close()
```

## finally:

<strike>Vote on the pull-request: https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/pull/1398</strike>  This was merged almost immediately, so the template should be fixed in the next setuptools release. It seems the only thing needed here was for someone to care enough to actually complain about it.

Comment: Thanks. This works for my own installation, and is really good to know. Is there a solution that would be more generally applicable, i.e., will work for end users out-of-the-box without requiring them to hack their pip installations?

Comment: No.  This needs to be addressed in setuptools directly, it's not `pip`.

Comment: Went over there to vote and saw the same thing. Wonder if this thread precipitated it or just a coincidence? :)

Comment: Ah, I see that you were the PR originator! Ok, so not a coincidence, and thank you!